# Enrollment's like table has days split into rows, format these as columns instead

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a table that holds student enrollments in a class that has the following rows:

```
Enrollment_id | Student_id | ... | Day | start_time | end_time| Location
```

For a student enrolled in say Math 101, which for example could be at 2pm to 4pm on Monday Tuesday, and 4pm to 5pm on Thursday, would have the following data in the table.

```
1 | x | 'Monday' | 14:00:00 | 16:00:00 | 'Class Room x'
1 | x | 'Tuesday' | 14:00:00 | 16:00:00 | 'Class Room x'
1 | x | 'Thursday' | 16:00:00 | 17:00:00 | 'Class Room x'
```

I need to create an export for this, that formats this students enrollments as the following:

```
Student_id | ... | M | T | W | T | F | Time | Location
x | ... | Y | Y | N | N | N | '14:00:00 - 16:00:00 | 'Class Room X'
x | ... | N | N | N | Y | N | '16:00:00 - 17:00:00 | 'Class Room X'
```

So it's essential grouping by the student_id, some course information, then by the time. Once grouped, it creates this Monday / Tuesday, ect. columns and puts either a Y / N if they have that class on that day. This is also by specific times, so the same class may have different times (IE labs, and classroom lectures) on different days, and these would be different rows.

Looking for help on how to write this as a subquery. Happy to provide additional info on the table, or other tables around it. I'm stumped on this one though, and I'm not even sure it's possible. Currently, this is done in a Python api using Sqlalchemy so either as a sqlalchemy or raw sql would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the CASE expressions like below.

```
SELECT student_id,
   ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN DAY = 'Monday'
              THEN 'Y'
              END),'N') AS 'M',
   ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN DAY = 'Tuesday'
        THEN 'Y'
        END),'N') AS 'T',
   ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN DAY = 'Wednesday'
        THEN 'Y'
        END),'N') AS 'W',
   ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN DAY = 'Thursday'
        THEN 'Y'
        END),'N') AS 'T',
   ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN DAY = 'Friday'
        THEN 'Y'
        END),'N') AS 'F',
   CONCAT(Start_time,'-',end_time) as Time,
   Location
   FROM student
   GROUP BY student_id,CONCAT(Start_time,'-',end_time),Location
```

Result set based on your sample data

```
student_id  M   T   W   T   F   Time                Location
 x          Y   Y   N   N   N   14:00:00-16:00:00   Class Room x
 x          N   N   N   Y   N   16:00:00-17:00:00   Class Room x
```

Comment: This worked beautifully! Thanks, I didn't think it would be so simple.

Comment: Glad it has helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select student_id, time, location,
       max(case when day = 'Monday' then 'Y' else 'N' end) as mon,
       max(case when day = 'Tuesday' then 'Y' else 'N' end) as tue,
       . . .
from t
group by student_id, time, location;
```

Because you are using Postgres, I would advise you to use booleans rather than characters for each day.  That results in the simpler:

```
select student_id, time, location,
       bool_or(day = 'Monday') as mon,
       bool_or(day = 'Tuesday') as tue,
       . . .
from t
group by student_id, time, location;
```